# Android theme set to black, but it is white in Android 4.1

Tags: android, eclipse

I have tried both `Theme.DeviceDefault` and `Theme.Black` in my styles.xml, and both make my 2.1 emulator become black correctly, but on the 4.1 emulator it stays white...am I doing something wrong?

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black" />

</resources>
```

PS: I presume the drop-down for "Theme" at the top of the Graphical Layout is just showing me what it would look like, it's not some kind of setting that's going somewhere (for the app)?

Comment: Have you tried android:Theme.Holo ?

Comment: Is this your only `styles.xml` or do you have another e.g. in some `values-xy` folder?

Comment: oooo I do have others. How do I know what are legitimate values to put in - presumably (since several xml files exist) they don't all support the same themes?

Comment: The Android system always chooses the most special values folder that fits best to your device.

Comment: I've just put `DeviceDefault` in for each XML file and now they're all dark. This seems the right solution to me - would you agree? It seems odd that the defaults are not set to "DeviceDefault" given its name!

Comment: @MattHandy, you could add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Android system always chooses the most special values folder that fits best to your device.

As example if you have a folder `values` and another folder `values-v14` the Android system takes resources from the latter if the device is v14 or newer.

Please refer to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

1.create new folder under res -> values-v13
2.create file style there and add this style :
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">`

in your manifast use this style for your application like this

```
<application
        android:name=".MainApp"        
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

that way on ICS version you use the Holo.light theme and pre ICS use the default you already created

Answer (score 1):

Setting it via styles doesn't actually work, but if you set it explicitly for application it works.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
```

Answer (score 0):

By default 4.0 and 4.1 give us white background but you can change it to black I face the same problem some days ago, if your project theme is set to be black then probably you change the Title while creating project to "Main" by default its "MainActivity" but if you change it to "Main" it will give you black backgrount/

I don't know my answer is relevant to your question or not but i think you talking about this if i am not wrong.